# Creating a label with value passed as a \newcommand argument?

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, labels

I made a \newcommand that implement figures into the body of the text to make my file look neat and flow. This is the code implementation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Figures packages & implementation
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx} %Handles images.
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} %Captions - labelfond BOLD

\newcommand{\fig}[5]{
    %%%% Figure %%%%
    \begingroup
    \setlength\belowcaptionskip{0.7\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=#2, width=#3]{Images/#1}
    \captionof{figure}{#4}
    \label{fig:#5}
    \endgroup
} %The input parameters are as such:
    % #1 - image's name in folder
    % #2 - desired height
    % #3 - desired width
    % #4 - caption
    % #5 - num of figure for labeling purposes (cref etc.)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\fig{example - image}{10cm}{10cm}{This is a cpation}{1}

\end{document}
```

This bit of code works fine, except the label {#5} is not being set as the input parameter i send, Instead the figure is labeled as fig:#5.

The idea is that each the user should be able to decide what will be the label for a certain picture through the input 5th parameter. how can i do it?

*if the original bug has no fix, an agreeable solution will be to name the label with the same name as the picture's name (i.e. the picture in the folder called Pineapple, then the label will be fig:Pineapple,

or

*the label will be numbered automatically with figure number.

Thanks for helping
:>

edit:
i added the execution command

Comment: don't show only snippets, always show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: your example is still not complete, \documentclass is missing. And we don't have "Imagename", replace this e.g. with `example-image`.

Comment: Have a look at the `easyfig` package!

Comment: Hm, you didn't test your example, or you would have realized that the path Image/ interferes and there should be no space in `example-image`. But beside this it works as expected. What do you think \label should do differently?

Comment: I cannot recreate the issue.  If I invoke after the figure, `\ref{fig:#5} and \ref{fig:1}`, I get `?? and 1`, as expected.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I obviously tested my proble at my own environmet. i change the 5-sentence caption and image name purely to reduce unnecessary info. the image in my article has a different name and it is spelled right.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - you are right. This is silly by me it works as you say...
I was confused cause the autocompletion showed it knows only "fig:#5", so i thought the compiler does'nt get parameter #5.
When i tried to cross red "fig:#5" i got the expected result (fig 1.1) so i though there is a problem.
Thanks for your reply
Thanks for the

Comment: You should use `\begin{center}` here not `\centering` (as you are not using `\begin{figure}` (why not?) Also note that while it is possible to use numbers in `\label` it is usually a bad idea as it works for latex but is confusing to anyone looking at the source if figure 5 has internal `\label{fig:1}`

Comment: Would you like the question to be closed, because it was based on a misunderstanding?

Comment: indeed. You may redeem it

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use the `easyfig` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{easyfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    By default, label is \verb|fig:<picture name>|
    \Figure[placement=h!, width=.5\linewidth, caption={Image a}]{example-image-a}
    
    But user can specify the label.
    \Figure[placement=h!, width=.5\linewidth, caption={Image b}, label={fig:b}]{example-image-b}
    
    \Figure[placement=h!, min size={.5\linewidth}{!}, max size={!}{.7\textheight}]{example-image-c}
    
    \cref{fig:example-image-a} and \cref{fig:b}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the work around. I changed my code to use easyfig as it is more commpact and neat + it satisfy my needs.
Thanks